# ngRepeat strange behaviour when its elements order change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am learning angularjs and I came across some behaviour that I can't understand. I render a list of items in ng-repeat, each has a button to remove itself from the $scope's array - this works as expected but once I added a sortable to the list strange things started to happen.

Here is the running example showing the issue:

https://embed.plnkr.co/eQWcxZ7p8CcACfk6Z53X/

In the example - if I move [^] item 4 (Rocket Launcher) to position 1 and use Rocket Launcher's delete [X] button the list gets updated (i.e. item 4 - Rocket Launcher - that was on position 1 is removed) but the other items delete buttons stop working. Basically moving items and deleting them somehow break the bindings (?).

#### The code:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.controller('myAppController', function($scope) {

    $scope.boxes = [];

    $scope.removeBoxItem = function(box, item) {
      console.log('Removing "' + item.name + '" form box "' + box.name + '"...');
      var index = box.items.indexOf(item);
      box.items.splice(index, 1);
      console.log(box);
    };

    this.init = function() {
      var e;
      e = new Box({
        name: 'Red box'
      });

      $scope.boxes.push(e);

      e.items.push(new Item({
        index: 1,
        name: 'Rock'
      }));
      e.items.push(new Item({
        index: 2,
        name: 'Scissors'
      }));
      e.items.push(new Item({
        index: 3,
        name: 'Paper'
      }));
      e.items.push(new Item({
        index: 4,
        name: 'Rocket launcher'
      }));

      e = new Box({
        name: 'Green box'
      });

      e.items.push(new Item({
        index: 1,
        name: 'Chuck the Plant'
      }));
      e.items.push(new Item({
        index: 2,
        name: 'Hamster'
      }));
      e.items.push(new Item({
        index: 3,
        name: 'Tentacle Chow'
      }));

      $scope.boxes.push(e);

    };

    this.init();

  });

  app.directive("sortable", ["$timeout", function($timeout) {
    return {
      template: '<div class="sortable" ng-transclude></div>',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        'handle': '@'
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        $timeout(function() {
          //console.log(element)

          var sortable = element.find('> div');
          console.log(sortable[0]);

          scope.sortable = Sortable.create(sortable[0], {
            handle: scope.handle || null
          });
        });
      }
    };
  }]);

}());


function Box(args) {
  this.name = args.name || null;
  this.items = [];
}

function Item(args) {
  this.index = args.index || null;
  this.name = args.name || null;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <style>
  .container {
    border: 1px solid #929292;
    padding: 5px;
  }

  .header {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #E2E2E2;
  }

  .body {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .body .item {
    border: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }

  .body .options {
    float: right;
  }

  .body .options .delete {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .body .options .handle {
    cursor: move;
  }

  .debug {
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-top: 1px dotted #929292;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myAppController as appCtrl">
    <div class="container">
      <div ng-repeat="box in boxes">
        <div class="header">{{ box.name }}</div>
        <div class="body">
          <div data-sortable="" data-handle=".handle">
            <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in box.items">
              {{item.index }}) {{ item.name }}
              <div class="options">
                <span ng-click="removeBoxItem(box, item)" class="delete">[X]</span>
                <span class="handle">[^]</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="debug">
        <pre>{{ boxes | json }}                    
          </pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script data-require="jquery@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="Sortable.js@1.6.0" data-semver="1.6.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Sortable/1.6.0/Sortable.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" data-semver="1.6.6" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am confused by this, in my real code things get even more broken - I made a collapsible directive that surrounds the "Boxes" so I can open and manipulate one at a time - in that case moving item 4 to position 1 and deleting it removes all items from the view (but not from the $scope). Than adding new item to the $scope's array causes items to correctly reappear. For now I created simpler version as I guess this is all somehow connected.

I am aware the sortable should set the objects indexes etc but for now I'd like to understand what is happening. I suspect I have some issues with understanding what is going on with scopes (?). Would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Need to use events from sortable library to adjust your scope data sort order.

Comment: Sortable.js acts on the DOM. But in AngularJS, the single point of truth is the model, not the DOM. The DOM is directly derived from the model. See https://plnkr.co/edit/pJrq3bEJuag7ficpYjTv?p=preview for example: if you reorder the elements of the first box, and then clicj the "Add" button I added at the top, everything will be reordered, because Sortable reordered elements in the DOM, behind the back of AngularJS, by acting on the DOM rather than by acting on the model. You need to use something that is integrated with AngularJS.

Comment: @JBNizet - ok, I understand that angular gets confused as Sortable.js modified the DOM, but then I remove data from the $scope.box.items array by calling controller's removeBoxItem - shouldn't angular re-render the ngRepeat than? It actually looks as it does as the item disappears both from the view and from the related $scope.box.items... but also the view functionality gets broken. It kind of looks like the model is updated properly but ngRepeat uses some outdated copy of/reference to this data. Just to be clear - I am sure you are right, just trying to comprehend what is actually happening.

Comment: So is the following generally true as the solution to fix this problem: make sure Sortable.js sets the indexes on that items array after sorting event finishes (item is moved) then angular can re-draw the list (sorting by the updated indexes).